# Need Help with a coupled SIR model Differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to create and solve a coupled delayed SIR model in Mathematica. I am getting negative points in my plot which doesn't make sense. Need help to figure out what am I doing wrong.
My code is

```
SS4 = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == - x1[t] ((0.3/(80*10^6)) y1[t] + (0.5/(80*10^6)) y2[t]), x2'[t] == - x2[t] ((0.5/(80*10^6)) y1[t] + (0.5/(50*10^6)) y2[t]), y1'[t] == x1[t] ((0.3/(80*10^6)) y1[t - 14] + (0.5/(80*10^6)) y2[
      t - 14]) - (1/16) y1[t - 14], y2'[t] == 
x2[t] ((0.5/(80*10^6)) y1[t - 14] + (0.5/(50*10^6)) y2[
      t - 14]) - (1/16) y2[t - 14], z1'[t] == (0.3/(80*10^6)) x1[t - 14] y1[t - 14],z2'[t] == (0.5/(50*10^6)) x2[t - 14] y2[t - 14],  x1[0] == 80*10^6, y1[0] == 150, y1[t /; t <= 0] == E^t, z1[0] == 0,
x2[0] == 50*10^6, y2[t /; t <= 0] == E^t, y2[0] == 100,  z2[0] == 0  }, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

After plotting the solutions I am getting

```
pp4 = Plot[{x1[t] /. SS4, y1[t] /. SS4, z1[t] /. SS4, x2[t] /. SS4, y2[t] /. SS4, z2[t] /. SS4}, {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Dashed, PlotLegends -> {"Susecptible", "Active", "Recovery"}]
```

[image]

Obviously the plot shouldn't go negative as it is going.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a source for the equations?  I think there is a mistake in how they're set up.  As written, conservation of mass is violated, which can lead to the negative values.  If you intend there to be a fixed 14-day duration in the infected stages `y1` and `y2`, then try something like:

```
SS4 = NDSolve[{
  x1'[t] == -x1[t] (0.3/(80*10^6) y1[t] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t]), 
  x2'[t] == -x2[t] (0.5/(80*10^6) y1[t] + 0.5/(50*10^6) y2[t]), 
  y1'[t] == x1[t] (0.3/(80*10^6) y1[t] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t]) - 
     x1[t - 14] (0.3/(80*10^6) y1[t - 14] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t - 14]),
  y2'[t] == x2[t] (0.5/(80*10^6) y1[t] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t]) - 
     x2[t - 14] (0.5/(80*10^6) y1[t - 14] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t - 14]),
  z1'[t] == x1[t - 14] (0.3/(80*10^6) y1[t - 14] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t - 14]),
  z2'[t] == x2[t - 14] (0.5/(80*10^6) y1[t - 14] + 0.5/(80*10^6) y2[t - 14]),
  x1[0] == 80*10^6, y1[0] == 150, y1[t /; t <= 0] == E^t, z1[0] == 0,
  x2[0] == 50*10^6, y2[t /; t <= 0] == E^t, y2[0] == 100, z2[0] == 0},
  {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}, {t, 0, 200}];

pp4 = Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], x2[t] . y2[t], z2[t]} /. SS4],
  {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Dashed, PlotLegends -> {"Susecptible", "Active", "Recovery"}]
```

[image]

Basically, the outflow from the infected pool should match the inflow 14 days ago (if there was mortality, you'd have to discount for survivorship).

As a side note, you might want to define some constants instead of re-typing the same numbers in your equations!

Comment: ah yes, makes sense. thank you